# Ktor - Static content routing

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I would love to understand better how Ktor is handling the routing for static content. I have the following hierarchy in my static folder (working directory):

```
- static
 - index.html
 - (some files)
 - static
  - css (directory)
  - js (directory)
  - (some files)
```

I'd like to serve all of them. So I was using directly this code in `routing`:

```
static {
  defaultResource("index.html", "static")
  resources("static")
}
```

Which works very well, but the issue is that it's taking the hand on all requests including my small `get`:

```
get("/smoketest"){
  call.respondText("smoke test!", ContentType.Text.Plain)
}
```

What would be the best to handle in general the static content in Ktor?

[Here is the code](https://github.com/vpasquier/sprint-review/blob/feature-34-reactjs/sprint-review-server/src/main/kotlin/com/sprintreview/Server.kt#L34-L54)

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "taking the hand" ?

Comment: I cannot hit this endpoint "/smoketest". Im always redirected to the index.html. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you post the complete routing setup? Also, what version of ktor are you on?

Comment: I've put the link at the end of the post. Thank you again for helping

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I tried reproducing it locally and made it work with two different approaches.

1. Put one of these in your static block

```kotlin
file("*", "index.html") // single star will only resolve the first part

file("{...}", "index.html") // tailcard will match anything
```

2. Or, put the following get handler as your last route:

```kotlin
val html = File("index.html").readText()
get("{...}") {
     call.respondText(html, ContentType.Text.Html)
}
```

The `{...}` is a tailcard and matches any request that hasn't been matched yet.

Documentation available here: http://ktor.io/features/routing.html#path

Edit:
For resources I made the following work:

```
fun Route.staticContent() {
    static {
        resource("/", "index.html")
        resource("*", "index.html")
        static("static") {
            resources("static")
        }
    }
}
```

I can't see your static files in the repository, so here is what it looks like in my project:
[image]

Comment: Hey Andreas, Thank a lot for your quick answer. Although the first one didn't work for me, displaying the index.html with the second one worked (and its a good trick this tail card). Unfortunately, I cannot find anyway to load all the resources I have in this index.html (for instance a js file in static/js folder at the level of index). Do you have a complementary code for this? (you can check my code again to see what I tried)

Comment: I also use this code to serve resources that are required in index.html:   `static("static") { files(File("app/static")) }`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and answer! It works like a charm

Comment: Works beautifully. The folder structure helped a lot!