# Image Tag in Ktor HTML DSL

Tags: image, kotlin, ktor

I am trying to get an image to display on a webpage through the ktor HTML DSL. The image won't appear, and the alt is showing.

I am currently using the IDE Intellij, and I can't think of where to put the image. I tried putting it in the src folder where the .kt file is, but it is still not seeing it.

img (src: "This is a picture!!", alt: "/img/picture.jpg")
Here is a source I used: https://github.com/celtric/kotlin-html/blob/master/README.md

The image is supposed to show but the alt shows instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put it in your resources folder.

The src folder is for code to be compiled.

The resources folder should be in `src/main/`.

Furthermore, you need to tell ktor to serve static files in your routing.

See the official documentation:
https://ktor.io/servers/features/static-content.html

Also, here is an example including the `img` tag: https://ktor.io/samples/feature/static.html

Also, take a look at my previous answer for more details regarding static content routing in ktor: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50965188/5335131