# Cannot serve static content with Ktor

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I try to use the Route.static function to serve static files, but it doesn't work. I have tried all kinds of combinations and folders in my working directory. Now I have a css under resources/static/css, and index.html under resources/static. If I write the following I don't get served anything :

```
@kotlin.jvm.JvmOverloads
fun Application.module(testing: Boolean = false) {

    val client = HttpClient(Apache) {}

    routing {
      static("root") {
        files("css")
        default("index.html")
      }
   }
}
```

I can however, from this answer : [Ktor - Static content routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50901472/ktor-static-content-routing), write :

```
        resource("/", "index.html")
        resource("*", "index.html")
```

Then I will get index.html under resources/static. I cannot however get anything else. What am I doing wrong here ?

Ref : https://ktor.io/servers/features/static-content.html#specifying-files-and-folders

Answer (score 3):

**The most correct config for static files**

```
static {
    staticRootFolder = File(""/*or environment.rootPath)*/) // project root dir
    files("static") // dir for all static files
}
```

Create a `static` folder next to your `server.jar` file and put anything there.

`https://example.com/file.txt`
`https://example.com/css/style.css`
`https://example.com/images/image.png`

Additionally:

```
tasks {
    val copyStatic = register("copyStatic", Copy::class) {
        from("$projectDir/static") {
            exclude("**/*.scss", "**/*.sass", "**/*.map")
        }
        into("${rootProject.buildDir}/static")
    }
    "build" {
        dependsOn(copyStatic)
        dependsOn(fatJar)
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked for me. If I am running a ktor project from the IntelliJ IDE, I created a directory at the project root level /static. Under /static, I created a /css and /js folders. So it serves the static files when debugging. When exporting the project as a .jar, wherever that jar is launched, I need to copy and paste the /static folder from the project.

Comment: @MarkLapasa  just create task for automatically copy static folder. I have updated my answer

Comment: It does not work with version `2.2.4`

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose that you have your project in the C:\ktor-project folder. If you want your Ktor server to use the following URLs and give back the content of the corresponding files below, then use the code at the bottom.

http://localhost:8080/root/main.css ->  C:\ktor-project\css\main.css
http://localhost:8080/root ->  C:\ktor-project\index.html
http://localhost:8080/root/styles.css ->  C:\ktor-project\resources\static-resources\styles.css

```
static("/root") {
    files("css")
    default("index.html")
    resources("static-resources")
}
```

The resources("static-resources") line can be a better choice than the files("css") line if the given styles.css file is built by your Gradle build. Most of the times you will need only one of them.

Comment: @user12182754 Did my answer help you?